# js dynatree plugin from <ul> structure - disable radiobutton selection if its root nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, dynatree, jquery-dynatree

I want to disable selection of all nodes, except leafs. 
I mean, user should be able to select (radiobutton check) nodes only if it's leaf node of the tree.
I see the docs and is indicated to use:

```
{title: "Sub-item 4.3 (hideCheckbox)", hideCheckbox: true },
```

But it's usefull if you create a tree from js data. I created the tree using an

markup.
I think, the solution is near if using:

```
<li data='....'>Text Node
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `data` attribute is parsed as JSON, and then used to expand the `data` options, so

```
<li data='"hideCheckbox": true'>Text Node
```

should work.

Comment: Note: this works for other properties too like `select: true` I imagine it works for all properties